# Java: Calling a super method which calls an overridden method

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, super

```
public class SuperClass
{
    public void method1()
    {
        System.out.println("superclass method1");
        this.method2();
    }

    public void method2()
    {
        System.out.println("superclass method2");
    }

}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass
{
    @Override
    public void method1()
    {
        System.out.println("subclass method1");
        super.method1();
    }

    @Override
    public void method2()
    {
        System.out.println("subclass method2");
    }
}



public class Demo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SubClass mSubClass = new SubClass();
        mSubClass.method1();
    }
}
```

my expected output:

> subclass method1
>   superclass method1
>   superclass method2

actual output:

> subclass method1
>   superclass method1
>   subclass method2

I know technically I have overriden a public method, but I figured that because I was calling the super, any calls within the super would stay in the super, this isn't happening. Any ideas as to how I can make it happen?

Comment: I suspect you might want to "prefer composition over inheritance".

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The keyword `super` doesn't "stick". Every method call is handled individually, so even if you got to `SuperClass.method1()` by calling `super`, that doesn't influence any other method call that you might make in the future.

That means there is no direct way to call `SuperClass.method2()` from `SuperClass.method1()` without going though `SubClass.method2()` unless you're working with an actual instance of `SuperClass`.

You can't even achieve the desired effect using Reflection (see [the documentation of `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object, Object...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object%2C%20java.lang.Object...%29)).

**[EDIT]** There still seems to be some confusion. Let me try a different explanation.

When you invoke `foo()`, you actually invoke `this.foo()`. Java simply lets you omit the `this`. In the example in the question, the type of `this` is `SubClass`.

So when Java executes the code in `SuperClass.method1()`, it eventually arrives at `this.method2();`

Using `super` doesn't change the instance pointed to by `this`. So the call goes to `SubClass.method2()` since `this` is of type `SubClass`.

Maybe it's easier to understand when you imagine that Java passes `this` as a hidden first parameter:

```
public class SuperClass
{
    public void method1(SuperClass this)
    {
        System.out.println("superclass method1");
        this.method2(this); // <--- this == mSubClass
    }

    public void method2(SuperClass this)
    {
        System.out.println("superclass method2");
    }

}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass
{
    @Override
    public void method1(SubClass this)
    {
        System.out.println("subclass method1");
        super.method1(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void method2(SubClass this)
    {
        System.out.println("subclass method2");
    }
}



public class Demo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SubClass mSubClass = new SubClass();
        mSubClass.method1(mSubClass);
    }
}
```

If you follow the call stack, you can see that `this` never changes, it's always the instance created in `main()`.

Comment: could someone please upload a diagram of this(pun intended) going through the stack? thanks in advance!

Comment: @laycat: There is no need for a diagram. Just remember that Java has no "memory" for `super`. Every time it calls a method, it will look at the instance type, and start searching for the method with this type, no matter how often you called `super`. So when you call `method2` on an instance of `SubClass`, it will always see the one from `SubClass` first.

Comment: @AaronDigulla, Can you explain more about the "Java has no memory for super"?

Comment: @Truman'sworld: as I said in my answer: using `super` doesn't change the instance. It doesn't set some hidden field "from now on, all method calls should start using `SuperClass`". Or to put it another way: The value of `this` doesn't change.

Comment: @AaronDigulla, so does that mean the super keyword are actually invoke the inherited methods in the subclass instead of go to the super class?

Comment: @Truman'sworld: No. `super` just affects the immediate method call. It doesn't "stick" or apply to any subsequent method calls which are based off `this`.

Answer (score 17):

You can only access overridden methods in the overriding methods (or in other methods of the overriding class).

So: either don't override `method2()` or call `super.method2()` inside the overridden version.

Answer (score 12):

I think of it this way

```
+----------------+
|     super      |
+----------------+ <-----------------+
| +------------+ |                   |
| |    this    | | <-+               |
| +------------+ |   |               |
| | @method1() | |   |               |
| | @method2() | |   |               |
| +------------+ |   |               |
|    method4()   |   |               |
|    method5()   |   |               |
+----------------+   |               |
    We instantiate that class, not that one!
```

Let me move that subclass a little to the left to reveal what's beneath...
(Man, I do love ASCII graphics)

```
We are here
        |
       /  +----------------+
      |   |     super      |
      v   +----------------+
+------------+             |
|    this    |             |
+------------+             |
| @method1() | method1()   |
| @method2() | method2()   |
+------------+ method3()   |
          |    method4()   |
          |    method5()   |
          +----------------+

Then we call the method
over here...
      |               +----------------+
 _____/               |     super      |
/                     +----------------+
|   +------------+    |    bar()       |
|   |    this    |    |    foo()       |
|   +------------+    |    method0()   |
+-> | @method1() |--->|    method1()   | <------------------------------+
    | @method2() | ^  |    method2()   |                                |
    +------------+ |  |    method3()   |                                |
                   |  |    method4()   |                                |
                   |  |    method5()   |                                |
                   |  +----------------+                                |
                   \______________________________________              |
                                                          \             |
                                                          |             |
...which calls super, thus calling the super's method1() here, so that that
method (the overidden one) is executed instead[of the overriding one].

Keep in mind that, in the inheritance hierarchy, since the instantiated
class is the sub one, for methods called via super.something() everything
is the same except for one thing (two, actually): "this" means "the only
this we have" (a pointer to the class we have instantiated, the
subclass), even when java syntax allows us to omit "this" (most of the
time); "super", though, is polymorphism-aware and always refers to the
superclass of the class (instantiated or not) that we're actually
executing code from ("this" is about objects [and can't be used in a
static context], super is about classes).
```

In other words, quoting from the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2):

> The form `super.Identifier` refers to the field named `Identifier` of the
>   current object, but with the current object viewed as an instance of
>   the superclass of the current class.
>
> The form `T.super.Identifier` refers to the field named `Identifier` of
>   the lexically enclosing instance corresponding to `T`, but with that
>   instance viewed as an instance of the superclass of `T`.

In layman's terms, `this` is basically an object (*the** object; the very same object you can move around in variables), the instance of the instantiated class, a plain variable in the data domain; `super` is like a pointer to a borrowed block of code that you want to be executed, more like a mere function call, and it's relative to the class where it is called.

Therefore if you use `super` from the superclass you get code from the superduper class [the grandparent] executed), while if you use `this` (or if it's used implicitly) from a superclass it keeps pointing to the subclass (because nobody has changed it - and nobody could).

Answer (score 8):

You're using the `this` keyword which actually refers to the "currently running instance of the object you're using", that is, you're invoking `this.method2();` on your superclass, that is, it will call the method2() on the object you're using, which is the SubClass.

Comment: true, and not using `this` won't help either. An unqualified invocation implicitly uses `this`

Comment: Why is this getting upvoted? This is not the answer to this question. When you write `method2()` the compiler will see `this.method2()`. So even if you remove the `this` it still will not work. What @Sean Patrick Floyd is saying is correct

Comment: @Shervin he's not saying anything wrong, he's just not making clear what happens if you leave out `this`

Comment: The answer is right in pointing out that `this` refers to the "concrete running instance class" (known in runtime) and not (as the poster seems to believe) to the "current compilation-unit class" (where the keyword is used, known in compile time). But it can also be misleading (as Shervin points) : `this` is also referenced implicitly with the plain  method call; `method2();` is the same as `this.method2();`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want superClass.method1 to call subClass.method2, make method2 private so it cannot be overridden.

Here's a suggestion:

```
public class SuperClass {

  public void method1() {
    System.out.println("superclass method1");
    this.internalMethod2();
  }

  public void method2()  {
    // this method can be overridden.  
    // It can still be invoked by a childclass using super
    internalMethod2();
  }

  private void internalMethod2()  {
    // this one cannot.  Call this one if you want to be sure to use
    // this implementation.
    System.out.println("superclass method2");
  }

}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

  @Override
  public void method1() {
    System.out.println("subclass method1");
    super.method1();
  }

  @Override
  public void method2() {
    System.out.println("subclass method2");
  }
}
```

If it didn't work this way, polymorphism would be impossible (or at least not even half as useful).

Answer (score 3):

```
class SuperClass
{
    public void method1()
    {
        System.out.println("superclass method1");
        SuperClass se=new SuperClass();
        se.method2();
    }

    public void method2()
    {
        System.out.println("superclass method2");
    }
}


class SubClass extends SuperClass
{
    @Override
    public void method1()
    {
        System.out.println("subclass method1");
        super.method1();
    }

    @Override
    public void method2()
    {
        System.out.println("subclass method2");
    }
}
```

calling

```
SubClass mSubClass = new SubClass();
mSubClass.method1();
```

outputs

> subclass method1
>  superclass method1
>  superclass method2

Answer (score 2):

Since the only way to avoid a method to get overriden is to use the keyword **super**, I've thought to move up the method2() from *SuperClass* to another new *Base* class and then call it from *SuperClass*:

```
class Base 
{
    public void method2()
    {
        System.out.println("superclass method2");
    }
}

class SuperClass extends Base
{
    public void method1()
    {
        System.out.println("superclass method1");
        super.method2();
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass
{
    @Override
    public void method1()
    {
        System.out.println("subclass method1");
        super.method1();
    }

    @Override
    public void method2()
    {
        System.out.println("subclass method2");
    }
}

public class Demo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SubClass mSubClass = new SubClass();
        mSubClass.method1();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
subclass method1
superclass method1
superclass method2
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` always refers to currently executing object.

To further illustrate the point here is a simple sketch:

```
+----------------+
|  Subclass      |
|----------------|
|  @method1()    |
|  @method2()    |
|                |
| +------------+ |
| | Superclass | |
| |------------| |
| | method1()  | |
| | method2()  | |
| +------------+ |
+----------------+
```

If you have an instance of the outer box, a `Subclass` object, wherever you happen to venture inside the box, even into the `Superclass` 'area', it is still the instance of the outer box.

What's more, in this program there is only one object that gets created out of the three classes, so `this` can only ever refer to one thing and it is:

[image]

as shown in the [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) 'Heap Walker'.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do it directly. One workaround would be to have a private internal implementation of method2 in the superclass, and call that. For example:

```
public class SuperClass
{
    public void method1()
    {
        System.out.println("superclass method1");
        this.internalMethod2();
    }

    public void method2()
    {
        this.internalMethod2(); 
    }
    private void internalMethod2()
    {
        System.out.println("superclass method2");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

"this" keyword refers to current class reference. That means, when it is used inside the method, the 'current' class is still SubClass and so, the answer is explained.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, this points to current object and the method invocation in java is polymorphic by nature. So, method selection for execution, totally depends upon object pointed by this. Therefore, invoking method method2() from parent class invokes method2() of child class, as the this points to object of child class. The definition of this doesn't changes, irrespective of whichever class it's used.

PS. unlike methods, member variables of class are not polymorphic.

Answer (score 0):

During my research for a similar case, I have been ending up by checking the stack trace in the subclass method to find out from where the call is coming from. There are probably smarter ways to do so, but it works out for me and it's a dynamic approach.

```
public void method2(){
        Exception ex=new Exception();
        StackTraceElement[] ste=ex.getStackTrace();
        if(ste[1].getClassName().equals(this.getClass().getSuperclass().getName())){
            super.method2();
        }
        else{
            //subclass method2 code
        }
}
```

I think the question to have a solution for the case is reasonable. There are of course ways to solve the issue with different method names or even different parameter types, like already mentioned in the thread, but in my case I dindn't like to confuse by different method names.

Comment: This code is dangerous and risky and expensive. Creating exceptions require the VM to construct a full stacktrace, comparing on only the name and not the full signature is error prone. Also, it reeks of a huge design flaw.

Comment: From the performance point of view, my code does not seem to produce more impact than 'new HashMap().size()'. However, I may have overlooked the concerns you have been thinking about and I am by fare not a VM expert. I see your doubt by comparing the class names, but it includes the package what makes me pretty sure, it is my parent class. Anyway, I like the Idea of comparing the signature instead, how would you do that? In general, if you have a smoother way to determine whether the caller is the superclass or anyone else I would appreciate to here about.

Comment: If you need to determine whether the caller is a super class I would seriously think longer if a redesign is in place. This is an anti-pattern.

Comment: I see the point but the general request of the thread is reasonable. In some situation, it can make sense a superclass method call stays in the superclass context with any nested method call. However, there seems to be no way to direct the method call accordingly in the Superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Further more extended the output of the raised question, this will give more insight on the access specifier and override behavior.

```
            package overridefunction;
            public class SuperClass 
                {
                public void method1()
                {
                    System.out.println("superclass method1");
                    this.method2();
                    this.method3();
                    this.method4();
                    this.method5();
                }
                public void method2()
                {
                    System.out.println("superclass method2");
                }
                private void method3()
                {
                    System.out.println("superclass method3");
                }
                protected void method4()
                {
                    System.out.println("superclass method4");
                }
                void method5()
                {
                    System.out.println("superclass method5");
                }
            }

            package overridefunction;
            public class SubClass extends SuperClass
            {
                @Override
                public void method1()
                {
                    System.out.println("subclass method1");
                    super.method1();
                }
                @Override
                public void method2()
                {
                    System.out.println("subclass method2");
                }
                // @Override
                private void method3()
                {
                    System.out.println("subclass method3");
                }
                @Override
                protected void method4()
                {
                    System.out.println("subclass method4");
                }
                @Override
                void method5()
                {
                    System.out.println("subclass method5");
                }
            }

            package overridefunction;
            public class Demo 
            {
                public static void main(String[] args) 
                {
                    SubClass mSubClass = new SubClass();
                    mSubClass.method1();
                }
            }

            subclass method1
            superclass method1
            subclass method2
            superclass method3
            subclass method4
            subclass method5
```