# Calling an Overridden Super Method Causes Infinite Recursion

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, overriding, stack-overflow

I am writing a program where an overridded method must call a method in the parent class, which in turn must call the original method of the overridden method. The overridden method must then also call its parent method.

This is the code I have:

```
public class Cow 
{
  public float hiCat()
  {
    ...
    return meow;
  }

  public float dog()
  {
    float meowz = hiCat();
    ...
  }
}

public class Moo extends Cow
{
  public float hiCat()
  {
    float dogBark = dog();
    float meows = super.hiCat();
    ...
  }
}
```

Which gives me a stack overflow error like so:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at Moo.hiCat(Moo.java:12)
at Cow.dog(Cow.java:63)
```

Line 12 in `Moo` is `float dogBark = dog();` and line 63 in `Cow` is `float meowz = hiCat();`.

I believe line 63 is the problem in `dog()`.

It seems like `hiCat()` in `class Moo` is calling `dog()` in `class Cow` like it's supposed to, but then `dog()` is calling the overridded version of `hiCat()` instead of the one it shares a class with. This confuses me because I am calling `hiCat()` in a regular way with no modifiers or anything.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Note: the program's structure must remain the same.

Main method is completely unrelated to the methods at hand:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    InputClass input = new InputClass();
    input.GenerateGUI();
}
```

Comment: Can you add your `main()` method?

Comment: You overrode `hiCat`. So `Moo.htCat` calls `Cow.dog` which calls `Moo.hiCat`. Infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question exists over here, which has the correct explanation: [Java: Calling a super method which calls an overridden method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595512/java-calling-a-super-method-which-calls-an-overridden-method)

I solved my particular problem by changing the `meowz` variable in `dog()` to a class variable, and then `hiCat()` can save to that variable, thus negating the need to call `hiCat()` from `dog()` and avoiding the infinite recursion.

Note that I also tested this in C#, and it does work with this setup. It appears that only Java has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are calling  `dog()` in side the overriding method of `hiCat()`, then when you the method executed, this line `float dogBark = dog()` calling `dog()` method then inside of `dog()` method in the super class calling again the `hiCat();` and `hiCat();` again calling `dog()` because the `hiCat();` method is overriding by sub class then it will call the the overriden one of `hiCat();` method..... so `StackOverflowError` happens

Answer (score 0):

You created cyclic dependency among your methods. Best way to handle these type of situations is to refactor the code and create private method _hiCat()

```
public class Cow 
{

private float _hiCat()
{
   ...
   return meow;
}

public float hiCat()
{
   return _hiCat();
}

public float dog()
{
   float meowz = _hiCat();
   ...
}
}

public class Moo extends Cow
{
 public float hiCat()
{
float dogBark = dog();
float meows = super.hiCat();
...
}
}
```