# Implementation of onDestroy to close a Billing Client

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I am trying to make example of Play Billing application described [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/play-billing-codelab/#0)

In Last step they have described

> To clean all the resources and unregister the observer, you just need to call BillingClient.endConnection. So define a method with this call inside BillingManager and then call it from GamePlayActivity.onDestroy:

according to above information I have made function called `destroy` like this in `BillingManager`java class.

```
public void destroy() {
        mBillingClient.endConnection();
    }
```

My Full BillingManager Class is like below

```
public class BillingManager implements PurchasesUpdatedListener {
    private final BillingClient mBillingClient;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private static final String TAG = "BillingManager";

    public BillingManager(Activity  activity) {

        mActivity = activity;
        mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(mActivity).setListener(this).build();
        mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponse) {
                if (billingResponse == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished() response: " + billingResponse);
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished() error code: " + billingResponse);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                Log.w(TAG, "onBillingServiceDisconnected()");
            }
        });
    }

    public void startPurchaseFlow(final String skuId, final String billingType) {
        // Specify a runnable to start when connection to Billing client is established
        Runnable executeOnConnectedService = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                BillingFlowParams billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                        .setType(billingType)
                        .setSku(skuId)
                        .build();
                mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(mActivity, billingFlowParams);
            }
        };

        // If Billing client was disconnected, we retry 1 time
        // and if success, execute the query
        startServiceConnectionIfNeeded(executeOnConnectedService);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchasesUpdated(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int responseCode,
                                   List<Purchase> purchases) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPurchasesUpdated() response: " + responseCode);
    }

    private static final HashMap<String, List<String>> SKUS;
    static
    {
        SKUS = new HashMap<>();
        SKUS.put(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP, Arrays.asList("gas", "premium"));
        SKUS.put(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS, Arrays.asList("gold_monthly", "gold_yearly"));
    }

    public List<String> getSkus(@BillingClient.SkuType String type) {
        return SKUS.get(type);
    }

    public void querySkuDetailsAsync(@BillingClient.SkuType final String itemType,
                                     final List<String> skuList, final SkuDetailsResponseListener listener) {
        // Specify a runnable to start when connection to Billing client is established
        Runnable executeOnConnectedService = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SkuDetailsParams skuDetailsParams = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                        .setSkusList(skuList).setType(itemType).build();
                mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuDetailsParams,
                        new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(int responseCode,
                                                             List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                                listener.onSkuDetailsResponse(responseCode, skuDetailsList);
                            }
                        });
            }
        };

        // If Billing client was disconnected, we retry 1 time
        // and if success, execute the query
        startServiceConnectionIfNeeded(executeOnConnectedService);
    }

    private void startServiceConnectionIfNeeded(final Runnable executeOnSuccess) {
        if (mBillingClient.isReady()) {
            if (executeOnSuccess != null) {
                executeOnSuccess.run();
            }
        } else {
            mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponse) {
                    if (billingResponse == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished() response: " + billingResponse);
                        if (executeOnSuccess != null) {
                            executeOnSuccess.run();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "onBillingSetupFinished() error code: " + billingResponse);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                    Log.w(TAG, "onBillingServiceDisconnected()");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        mBillingClient.endConnection();
    }
}
```

And My GamePlayActivity is like below

```
public class GamePlayActivity extends FragmentActivity implements BillingProvider {

@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

// I want call method here
    }

}
```

Now I want call above function in my game play activity. I have no idea how to call it.

Comment: `new BillingManager().destroy()` would be a good start... Hard to answer without seeing the rest of this class and how you interact with it. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 it can be done using casting activity also

Comment: @AmitVaghela I have added full code please check it

Comment: try link ((MainActivity) mContext).onDestroy(); in your activity and inform if not done@Priya

Comment: That cannot be the full code. There's no onCreate method for your Activity

Comment: I have added mBillingManager.destroy(); and its working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it mentioned in documentation

> call it from GamePlayActivity.onDestroy

but you defined your own method.

Override `onDestroy` method of GamePlayActivity and put `mBillingClient.endConnection();` into it.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mBillingClient.endConnection();
}
```

Comment: Could also call that other destroy method within onDestroy

Comment: @Priya that's really not necessary. Also, it's a method call - so just do it

Comment: its giving me error that mBillingClient can not resolved

Comment: @Priya, You should already have an instance of BillingManager. Do `bm.destroy()`. Otherwise `new BillingManager().destroy()` will execute your method, but I guess if you have to do this, there is a huge mistake in your logic.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your Activity already has an instance of the BillingManager

```
public class GamePlayActivity extends FragmentActivity implements BillingProvider {

    BillingManager bm;  // assign this in onCreate 

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        bm.destroy();
   }

}
```

Comment: Is it required to put the bm.destroy() above the super.onDestroy() line ?

Comment: Super is reqiuired to be called first

Comment: Can you describe it briefly. Thanks

Comment: @YasiruNayanajith You want call the destroy method of the framework before your own application https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595512/java-calling-a-super-method-which-calls-an-overridden-method