# Java - Access Modifiers and Which Methods Are Called

Tags: java, inheritance, this, super, access-modifiers

So I have the following two cases:

**Case 1:**

```
public class Person {
   private String name = "Person";
   private String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void printName() {
      System.out.println( getName() );
   }
}

public class Student extends Person {
   private double gpa = 0;
   private String getName() {
      return “Student”;
   }
}

public class Driver {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Person p = new Person();
      Student s = new Student();

      p.printName();  // “Person”
      s.printName();  // “Person”
   }
}
```

**Case 2:**

```
public class Person {
   private String name = "Person";
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void printName() {
      System.out.println( getName() );
   }
}

public class Student extends Person {
   private double gpa = 0;
   public String getName() {
      return “Student”;
   }
}

public class Driver {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Person p = new Person();
      Student s = new Student();

      p.printName();  // “Person”
      s.printName();  // “Student”
   }
}
```

Case 2 makes the most sense (it's intended behavior).

But why does Case 1 not output the same as Case 2 ("Person" instead of "Student")?

From what I understand, non-static calls implicitly use `this`. And from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4595762/3903342), `this` and `super` don't "stick". Thus, for the first case, `getName()` should use `Student`'s implementation as `this` refers to the `Student` instance (regardless of access modifiers). But that doesn't appear to be the case..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Case 1, `Student#getName` does **not** override `Person#getName`, as the methods are `private`, meaning they are not accessible to other classes.  Because `Student#getName` implicitly overrides `Person#getName` (since both are now `public`), `Student` is printed in Case 2.

Comment: I'm trying to learn Java too. Could these also be set to protected and still work?

Comment: @DanielZuzevich Absolutely!  As long as the child class is able to override the method from its parent, then the child will call its `getName`.

Comment: It's helpful to note that `public` object methods in Java are also [`virtual`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function).  Hence why case 2 works the way it does; this isn't the case in C++/C# which require the `virtual` keyword on `Person`'s `getName` to work this way.

Answer (score 0):

In each case `Person.printName()` calls `getName()`.

In `Case 1`, the only visible version is `Person.getName()`, hence that is called for both `Person` and `Student`.

In `Case 2`, `Student.getName()` overrides `Person.getName()`, hence the former is called.

So the different visibility applied to `getName()` influences the outcome. When it's `public` (or `protected`), it can be over-ridden and the method called will depend on the object. When it's `private`, there is no over-riding and `Person.getName()` is always called.