# Is it possible to make methods non-virtual in Java?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, virtual

i am newbie in java and i usually used c++ i just wondering this code works

```
public class ParentClass {
    public void methodA() {
        System.out.println("This is Parent A Method");
        whoAmI();
    }

    public void methodB() {
        System.out.println("This is Parent B Method and I am Calling Method A");
        whoAmI();
        methodA();
    }
}

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    @Override
    public void methodA() {
        System.out.println("This is Child A Method and I am Calling Parents Method A");
        whoAmI();
        super.methodA();
    }

    @Override
    public void methodB() {
        System.out.println("This is Child B Method and I am Calling Parents Method B");
        whoAmI();
        super.methodB();
    }
}
```

```
ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
c.methodB();
```

and I expected output like this

```
This is Child B Method and I am Calling Parents Method B
This is Parent B Method and I am Calling Method A
This is Parent A Method
```

but was

```
This is Child B Method and I am Calling Parents Method B
This is Parent B Method and I am Calling Method A
This is Child A Method and I am Calling Parents Method A
This is Parent A Method
```

so i realized that in java all non-static methods are by default virtual functions like virtual keyword in c++.

is there any way to make output like this?

```
This is Child B Method and I am Calling Parents Method B
This is Parent B Method and I am Calling Method A
This is Parent A Method
```

Comment: The code - as is - won't compile. Method `whoAmI()` is undefined.

Comment: he just forgot to show it to us, no biggie

Comment: If you want to always call `methodA` of class `Parent` within `methodB` of `Parent`, then you could declare`methodA` in `Parent` as `final` or `private`, preventing it from being overwritten. If this is not an option, then there is no way to do what you want due to [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch#:~:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20dynamic%20dispatch,(OOP)%20languages%20and%20systems.) (my C++ knowledge is a bit rusty, but iirc, the behaviour in C++ should be the same).

Comment: whoAmI() is just plain display function.
    public void whoAmI() {
        System.out.println("I am instance Of B");
    }

Comment: The only question here is *why* you expected that output. It isn't correct, and C++ would behave the same way as Java here, as long as the methods are `virtual`, which is the default in Java.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: i was studing java and in c++ there is virtual table to call function in runtime but in java there is no comments on this question. so i just want to know is there any way to ignore keyword virtual(c++) in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the `methodA`'s impl of `ParentClass` in a seperate private method:

```
public class ParentClass {
    public void methodA() {
        interMethodA();
    }

    private void interMethodA() {
        System.out.println("This is Parent A Method");
        whoAmI();
    }

    public void methodB() {
        System.out.println("This is Parent B Method and I am Calling Method A");
        whoAmI();
        interMethodA();
    }
}
```

And the `ChildClass` remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

The code - as is - does not compile since method `whoAmI()` is undefined. By removing the calls to this method, [I was able to reproduce the output](https://ideone.com/noymsU).

---

From what I understand, you want to ensure that `methodA` in `Parent` is called from `methodB` in `Parent`. Since [dynamic dispatching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20dynamic%20dispatch,(OOP)%20languages%20and%20systems) is used in Jjava to determine which actual implementation is called, we have to enforce that `methodA` cannot be overridden. As @MarquisofLorne pointed out, C++ uses dynamic dispatch aswell, if `methodA` is defined as `virtual` in `Parent`.

To enforce that dynamic dispatch always results in a call to `Parent`'s `methodA`, there are two general approaches that come to my mind: declaring `methodA` as `final` and declaring `methodA` as `private`.

---

#### Approach one: declare `methodA` in `Parent` as `final`

When going down this route, `Child` cannot re-define `methodA`, i.e. the code would result in a compile-time error if `methodA` is not removed from `Child`.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/nUSTJ2)

---

#### Approach two: declare `methodA` in `Parent` as `private`

This approach is similar to the first approach, but allows you to retain `methodA` in `Child`, albeit the `@Override`-annotation must be removed since private methods cannot be overridden.

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/mHZTd7)

Comment: C++ only uses dynamic despatch if you specify `virtual`, but it is the default in Java. This may be the root of the OP's problem.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne huh... as I said... my C++ is rusty =) added this information to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You got:

```
This is Child B Method and I am Calling Parents Method B
This is Parent B Method and I am Calling Method A
This is Child A Method and I am Calling Parents Method A
This is Parent A Method
```

Instead of

```
This is Child B Method and I am Calling Parents Method B
This is Parent B Method and I am Calling Method A
This is Parent A Method
```

Simply Bacause, In Java calling `methodA()` or `this.methodA()` in your `methodB()` of `ParentClass`  calls the method off of the calling object or instance, Yet the instance is an instanceof `ChildClass`. Java treats `methodA()` and `this.methodA()` as same. The `this` keyword in Java actually refers to the "currently running instance of the object you're using". Meaning, the overridding `methodA()` of ChildClass will be called instead of `methodA()` of ParentClass.

Here is a suggestion, to get the expected output, simply apply modifications on the overridding `methodA()` of `ChildClass` by commenting out the printing line.
Otherwise reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595512/java-calling-a-super-method-which-calls-an-overridden-method#:%7E:text=If%20you%20follow%20the%20call,instance%20created%20in%20main()%20.&text=You%20can%20only%20access%20overridden,()%20inside%20the%20overridden%20version.) for more details.